# How to call a function inside a private class whose name is identical with another function?

Tags: java, function, compiler-errors

Consider following class:

```
class Foo
{
    private class Bar
    {
        int operatedNumber;
        Bar(int x, int y)
        {
            operatedNumber = operate(x,y);
        }
        int operate(int x)
        {
           return x*2; 
        }
    }
    public int operate(int x, int y)
    {
        return x+y;
    }
    public Foo()
    {
        Bar b = new Bar(3,5);
    }
}
```

I am getting compile time error `The method operate() is not applicable for the arguments (int, int).`

Is there a way to call the second `operate()` function?

Comment: Note that there are other issues with your code, beyond the problem you've shown. It's helpful to have an example which *only* has the issue in the question.

Comment: @SJuan76: It really *is* important. The OP wants to call the method in the enclosing class. It's not well expressed in the title, but the body is reasonably clear.

Comment: There is something bad in your main, to get an instance of `Bar` you need first to hve an instance of `Foo`, apart that your method operate is void and you are returning something.

Comment: `public void operate(int x, int y)` can't return a value.

Comment: @SJuan76: Yes it is. When you fix the other issues (the return type of the second method and the construction of the instance of `Bar`), you *do* get an error unless you use `Foo.this` as per my answer. I've already tried it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok, I had the idea that you always had to use `[OuterClass].this.[method]` syntax, even without the name matching (I always write it anyway). My bad.

Comment: I have fixed the issues in my code. Thank you for your notice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to call the second operate() function?

Yes - you can qualify it with `Foo.this` to refer to the enclosing instance of `Foo`:

```
operatedNumber = Foo.this.operate(x,y);
```

Comment: @jgitter: I know it's not static. That's why it's `Foo.this` rather than `Foo`.

Comment: Yeah - I already removed my comment... misread first time through.  Although this is the right answer, this leaves much to be desired in terms of design.  I would rather refactor this class.